# HDMI to micro usb?

Tags: hdmi, usb-power

If you got a Micro-USB cable and adapted it to a HDMI cable, then connected it between your Raspberry Pi B+ and your Kindle Fire HD, would it work as a monitor?

Answer (score 2):

Very unlikely. This is not simply a case of connector shape and size, but one of sending the proper signals and establishing the correct communications handshake. Not to mention a different number of wires.

However, you could use the Kindle Fire to access your Pi using XRDP as described [here](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2014/05/30/connect-your-raspberry-pi-to-your-kindle-to-create-a-diy-productivity-tablet-raspberry_pi-piday-raspberrypi/), this is a much simpler solution and allows remote access over wifi.